# Stack Dash Application

Tags: app, mac-os-x

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]
[image]

### About

Stack Dash is a Mac OSX dashboard widget for Stack Exchange for displaying reputation, questions, answers and badges for a specified user and site.

This widget was put together originally right after the SO api was put into Beta.
I made this because I wanted to understand how to make a dashboard widget.
It is very rough so please go easy on it!

#### License

Released under the [BSD license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php)

#### Download

http://github.com/downloads/AidenMontgomery/Stack-Dash/Stack%20Dash.wdgt.v0.0.2.zip

#### Platform

Mac OSX dashboard

### Contact

Aiden Montgomery created Stack Dash. Leave feedback here and raise issues on the Git Hub project.

### Code

Stack Dash was created using Dashcode and makes use of HTML, CSS, javascript, jQuery and javascript resources provided by Dashcode.
The main language used is javascript with some HTML and css thrown in.

Anyone can access the public Git Hub repository at http://github.com/AidenMontgomery/Stack-Dash

Comment: Change the font to Lucida Sans and I am damn happy. Nice work :D

Comment: Thank you Radek. I have updated the font and it certainly looks nicer. Download the latest version to try it.